# Multiple buck convertors on one plug/power source

Tags: voltage, power

I have a question in regards to using multiple buck convertors.
I want to use a 12v plug/supply to run one wire to the 12v, two 5volts and one 8volt. What I want to know if it’s possible to have a wire run to the 12v (without buck convertor) and then have separate buck convertors on each of the other powers. I.e one for the 2 5volts ( or have one each) and one for the 8volts. Is that possible. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Post datasheet for the specific devices you plan to use and create and post a schematic of the proposed circuit so that you question may be more clear.

Comment: Add a diagram showing how you want to connect the converters.  They can be parallel off the same source or cascaded, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, provided that the 12V supply can provide the total power required by all the loads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your power sequence. If 12V can come on before the 8V and 5V, *and they don't interact*, then this can work.

If however there is some control interaction between the 5V and 8V and the stuff powered by 12V (like speakers, motors, solenoids, etc.) then you need to make sure that stuff is turned off until the other rails are stable.

One technique is to make a **power good** signal from the lower supplies that can hold off (mute) the 12V-connected drivers until the rest of the power is stable and the system is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. From the 12volts plug I want it to power one device that has 8volts on a arduino board that has audio card and leds. Again one some sort of arduino board that requires only 5volts. The 12volts has a remote that operates leds. Basically I am only powering lights or a 5volt media player. And I want them to work simultaneously.